# Correct way of deleting a model record with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a controller that lists all the units-of-measure in the system. When a user chooses a specific record in the `Uom` model I want to be able to delete it. I'm using Ember-Data beta-2. Here's what I have so far:

```
App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRecord: function(id) {
            console.log("deleting: " + id);
            var promisedDelete = this.store.find('uom',id).then(function(uom){
                uom.deleteRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The action `deleteRecord` is called passing in a valid ID and a promise is returned. Using the `then()` functionality of the promise I then call Ember's `deleteRecord()` when the promise has been fulfilled and it appears to work locally. I say that because this record immediately disappears from the screen and the Ember Debugger. Unfortunately the delete has not been persisted to the backend and a reload of hte page immediately brings back the locally "deleted" record.

My questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable way to execute a *local* delete?
2. How do I persist a delete to the backend?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will have to call `uom.save()` to persist the change to the backend after calling `uom.deleteRecord()`.

What you are doing could work, but seems a bit complicated (for example `this.store.find('uom',id)` will result into an unnecessary request to the backend). Try this:

```
App.UomsItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRecord: function() {
            this.get('model').destroyRecord();
            // .destroyRecord() only exists in recent versions of ED
            // for previous versions use .deleteRecord() followed by .save()
            // (though you should really consider upgrading :))
        }
    }
);

App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'uoms_item'
});
```

and in your template you will have something like this:

```
{{#each content}}
    {{name}} <a href="#" {{action "deleteRecord" this}}>Delete</a>
{{/each}}
```

EDIT to answer comment below: If `this.get('model')` is returning a promise, the following should work.

```
        deleteRecord: function() {
            this.get('model').then(function(item) {
                item.destroyRecord();
            })
        }
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant way of doing it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you update this answer for the newer version of Ember data? It returns a promise for `get('model')`.

Answer (score 8):

In ember-data v1.0.0-beta.4 they added a destroyRecord method which does the delete and save in one call. Which you can use like this:

```
   this.get('model').destroyRecord().then(function() {
      router.transitionTo('users');
   });
```

Answer (score 3):

The `deleteRecord` method can be called on any instance of `DS.Model` class. It removes the record form the **Store** But it will not persist in the backend.

`App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRecord: function(id) {
            console.log("deleting: " + id);
            var promisedDelete = this.store.find('uom',id).then(function(uom){
                uom.deleteRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});`

For the deletion to persist in the backend, we have to call save method on that record as(                          same as createRecord() followed by save() to save the record in backend) :

`App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRecord: function(id) {
            console.log("deleting: " + id);
            var promisedDelete = this.store.find('uom',id).then(function(uom){
                uom.deleteRecord();
                uom.save(); //The deletion will persist now
            });
        }
    }
});`

Alternatively, you can also use `destroyRecord()` method of `DS.Model` class which persists deletion.

`App.UomsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        deleteRecord: function(id) {
            console.log("deleting: " + id);
            var promisedDelete = this.store.find('uom',id).then(function(uom){
                uom.destroyRecord();
            });
        }
    }
});`